# How to mock aiofiles.open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-aiofiles

I'm trying to mock `aiofiles.open` and failing.

This is my code: `ds_feature_store/main.py`

```
async def read_json(path):
    async with aiofiles.open(path, "r") as f:
        return (
            path.removeprefix(f"{SCHEMAS_PATH}/").removesuffix(".json"),
            json.loads(await f.read()),
    )

async def startup_engine():
for feature_group, schema in await asyncio.gather(
    *[
        read_json(os.path.join(SCHEMAS_PATH, file))
        for file in os.listdir(SCHEMAS_PATH)
        if file.endswith(".json")
    ]
):
    feature_store_schemas[feature_group] = schema
```

This is how I'm trying to patch these functions calls.

```
with patch("ds_feature_store_api.main.os.listdir") as os_listdir:
    os_listdir.return_value = ["events_main.json", "events_extra.json"]
    with patch("ds_feature_store_api.main.aiofiles.open") as aiofiles_open:
        aiofiles_open.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.read = AsyncMock(return_value=b'{"record_identifier": "id"}')
```

The patch to `os.listdir` works, but the patch to `aiofiles.open` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Couldn't you patch `read_json` directly and return a dictionary?